# DotNetOpenAuth: Want to access username while storing Nonce

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I am using DotNetOpenAuth 4.0.20926 and trying to implement an OAuth2 based Authentication server with Db Nonce provider.

For some purpose I want to access username in NonceStore's StoreNonce function while processing the GetToken request.
I am not getting a way to retrieve Username in that call.

How can I solve this problem?

---

Hey Andrew thanks for your reply and DotNetOpenAuth.

My GetToken Method is like this

```
  public ActionResult Token()
  {
     string userName = "";  
     //Want to fetch username here 
     //Using username here 
     var result = this.authorizationServer.HandleTokenRequest(this.Request);
     return result.AsActionResult();
  }
```

And I want to fetch the username before calling HandleTokenRequest.
 Is there any Message Parser or Helper method to fetch the username from the request data / Code value .

Comment: The point at which you want to use the username isn't quite possible. There isn't a *user* associated with the HTTP request directly as the request to a Token endpoint comes from the client app. Some authorization grant comes in, and inside that there *can* be an authorizing username, but you'd need to decipher the authorization grant to discover it (and validate it first). Before I can make a recommendation though, I'd need to know what you're using it for.

Answer (score 1):

As you've observed, the interface does not pass the username into the `StoreNonce` method. So the only way you may possibly be able to get the username would be for you to discover what it is first, before you instantiate your `INonceStore` instance, and pass it to that nonce store first, so that later when `StoreNonce` is invoked, it already knows the username.

That said, I believe any design where storing and checking a nonce requires the username needs some rethinking. Not only is it a mixing of concerns that otherwise should remain separate, you may be limiting yourself going forward or even introducing security holes.